# Aurelia-validation ensure dependency issue

Tags: validation, aurelia

I have 2 ensure - validation decorators for 2 fields: password and retypePassword. I want to check the equality of those 2 fields when I fill the retypePassword field.

The problem is that when I type the exactly the same password in those two fields, it says that the passwords does not match.

```
@ensure(function(elem: ValidationGroup) {
    elem
        .isNotEmpty()
        .isStrongPassword()
}) password: string;

@ensure(function(elem: ValidationGroup) {
    elem
        .isNotEmpty()
        .isStrongPassword()
        .isEqualTo(elem.subject.password, "password")
}) retypePassword: string;
```

I've run the debugger and I saw that elem.subject.password is UNDEFINED when the line .isEqualTo(elem.subject.password, "password") is being executed.

How can I solve that? How can I test the equality of those passwords? Why elem.subject.password is undefined?

Thank you respectfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [official documentation](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/master/doc/Intro.md#configcomputedfromarrayofbindingpaths) there is a specification about how to do it via fluent API.

To do it using the `@ensure` decorator you can use something like:

```
@ensure((elem: ValidationGroup) => {
        elem
            .isNotEmpty()
            .isStrongPassword()
            .isEqualTo((parent = elem) => { return parent.result.properties.password.latestValue }, "password")
    }) retypePassword: string;
```